# Solve equation for x in d1+d2 =d1*d2

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations

Im trying to solve one equation which I will be using in one software.

I have two fixed points a and b in 2D space and also point c in which i know just coordinate x .

I need to solve coordinate y for point c. This equation can have more solutions. In this equation must be true that

s2*d1 + s1+d2 =d1*d2

where: 
d1 = squared distance between points a and c
d1 = squared distance between points b and c
s1 = variable which must be contained in equation
s2 = variable which must be contained in equation

Here is the link for Desmos: 
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/g85twlnqcx

Comment: Your wording is not very clear, please expose the problem in more details.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, your wording is not very clear.

If I try to understand, you have two numbers $(s_1,s_2)$, the coordinates $(x_a,y_a)$ for point $A$, $(x_b,y_b)$ for point $B$, $(x_c,y_c)$ for point $C$ and you want to solve for $y_c$ the equation
$$s_2 d_1+s_1 d_2=d_1 d_2$$ 
where 
$$d_1=(x_a-x_c)^2+(y_a-y_c)^2 \qquad \text{and} \qquad d_2=(x_a-x_c)^2+(y_a-y_c)^2$$ Expanding, you will end with a quartic equation in $y_c$
$$y_c^4+\alpha \,y_c^3+\beta\, y_c^2+\gamma \,y_c+\delta=0$$ where
$$\alpha=-2(y_a+y_b)$$
$$\beta=-2 x_c (x_a+x_b)+4 y_a y_b+x_a^2+y_a^2+x_b^2+y_b^2+2 x_c^2-s_1-s_2$$
$$\gamma=-2 y_a \left(-2 x_b x_c+x_b^2+y_b^2+x_c^2\right)-2 y_b \left(-2 x_a
   x_c+x_a^2+y_a^2+x_c^2\right)+2 s_2 y_a+2 s_1 y_b$$
$$\delta=\left(\left((x_a-x_c)^2+y_a^2\right) \left((x_b-x_c)^2+y_b^2\right)+2 s_2
   x_a x_c-s_2 x_a^2-s_2 y_a^2+2 s_1 x_b x_c-s_1 x_b^2-s_1
   y_b^2-s_1 x_c^2-s_2 x_c^2\right)$$

Comment: Thank you, this is what I tried to ask

Comment: @PatrikBašo. You are welcome ! Now, have fun with the quartic ! I strongly suggest numerical methods.

Comment: I found already some equations on stackoverflow , so I hope it will be working 